# How to get the last shape of a specific type?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I need to find the last path or circle in a paper, in order to perform further calculations to draw more elements, and calling `paper.bottom` only gets the last element. Is there any way to get shapes of specific types, e.g. `bottom.path`, `bottom.circle` or to traverse for the n'th child?

I want to avoid using jQuery selectors, as i can't retrieve any properties from those.

An example of a paper populated with shapes:

```js
var paper = Raphael('paper',500,500);
var c1 = paper.circle(100,100,50)
var p1 = paper.path("M10 20l70 0")
var c2 = paper.circle(200,100,50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for the bottom element will get you, well, the bottom element (along the Z axis) - which is undesired. Consider a case where the Z ordering of elements is altered - perhaps by calling [`Element.toBack()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.toBack) - that will invalidate the check altogether.

Instead you may want to aim for a more semantic approach by iterating over the elements array and retrieving the last element of a certain type (e.g. *circle*).

Raphaël also allows for [extending the built-in set of functions](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.fn), so we can attach a function to the paper element solely for that purpose. The following snippet shows an example of such a function which returns the last element of the passed type from the paper, or `false` if no such element was found:

```js
Raphael.fn.last = function(type) {
    var element;
    this.forEach(function(el) {
        if (el.type == type) {
            element = el;
        }
    });
    return element || !!element;
};
```

Be sure to attach this function before any instanciation of paper elements. Than it's only a matter of calling it, passing the desired element type:

```js
var r = Raphael(paper, '100%', '100%');
// ...
// add elements etcetera
// ...
var lastCircle = r.last('circle');
```

Note that for the suggested implementation this can result in heavy operations - if the paper contains many elements, but the purpose here is to grant you with the notion of functionality extension, and kick-start the thinking process. Feel free to improve the function to increase its efficiency.

---

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E3QkW/5/)

Comment: Nice. One way to possibly make this more efficient would be to store your various shapes in (semantically-named) sets when you create them. E.g. create a set called AllCircles, and push each of your circles into it. Then you would only have to loop through the relevant set, and not through the whole paper.

Comment: nice idea, @Ben, although this would require some maintenance - you'd have to add each new shape to the relevant set, which could make coding slightly more awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **how to traverse for the nth child**: Just put your paths in a set and they're indexed like any ordinary array. You can easily call out any number from that set, and get full access to its properties:

```
var myPaper = Raphael('container', '800', '600');

myPaper.setStart();
var circ1 = myPaper.circle(50, 50, 40);
var circ2 = myPaper.circle(150, 50, 40);
var circ3 = myPaper.circle(250, 50, 40);
var circ4 = myPaper.circle(350, 50, 40);
var allCircles = myPaper.setFinish();

allCircles[2].attr({fill: "blue"});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/eE7xS/